Add options to a column in AEM grid component
I would like to add some options to a column in an AEM Grid component. For example:
I have three columns on desktop:
[Rich text]---[Image]---[Title]

On mobile (they will be in column direction) I want to change the order of the columns and hide the image. The result should be like below.
[Title]
[Rich text]

Therefore I want to add 2 options to each column:

Hide this column on mobile (true/false)
Set mobile column order (1, 2, 3, 4...)

Is that at all possibe in AEM?

You can define three responsive container components at your template in respect to you [Rich text]---[Image]---[Title] for desktop. In mobile view (use out of the box AEM Emulator) you can select Layout mode and you can hide the required container.
